# How to know when the $_FILES array is empty

Tags: php

How can I know that the FILES does not contain an image, and adapt my code accordingly?
I want something like:

```
if(expression_that_check_FILES_array_isnot_empty)
{
   do sth;
}
else
{
   do sthElse;
}
```

Comment: have you tried empty() or isset()?

Comment: what about `empty` clause? `if (!empty($_FILES)){ ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks  [Pavel Janicek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/855636/pavel-janicek) for his answer in comment.
I used this:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)){
   do sth;
}
else{
   do sthElse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

```
if($_FILES['file']['name']!="")
{
   do sth;
}
else
{
   do sthElse;
}
```

Comment: I want sth that don't need the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']))
{
   do sth;
}
else
{
   do sthElse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

```
if(!isset($_FILES["file"]["size"]) || ($_FILES["my_file_name"]["size"] == 0) || (!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"]) {
    do sth; // Throw Error
} else {
   do sthElse; //Upload 
}
```